# How to return Observable from Callback

Tags: angular, interface, sdk, observable

I have a service in which I want to implement the logic of an SDK.
From this SDK I want to call an event that returns a payload.
I want to create a method in which the event is called and wrap it in an Observable to be able to subscribe to the response of the event.
I as well created an interface in order to assure type-safety of the sdk's response.

This is what has been created so far:

```
export interface SdkPayload{
     avatar,
     name,
     jobTitle,
     availability
    }

export class TestService {
    sdk:someSDK;
    

     //method that returns an Observable
    getPayload$(): Observable<SdkPayload[]> {
```

//create new Observable of type defined in Interface
return new Observable<SdkPayload[]>((subscriber) => {
const callbackFunction =
(sdkPayload:SdkPayload[]) => {

```
                    this.someSDK.on('connected', (payload) => {
                      
                        payload.greeting.agent.avatar,
                        payload.greeting.agent.name,
                        payload.greeting.agent.jobTitle,
                        payload.availability;
                    });
                    
                    subscriber.next(sdkPayload);
                };
                this.customerSDK.on('connected', callbackFunction);
                return () => {
                    this.customerSDK('off', callbackFunction);
                };
            });
        }
```

Component:

```
    export class AppComponent{
       payloadResults$: Observable<SdkPayload[]>;
    
    constructor (private service:TestService){}
    
    callMethod(){
     this.payloadResults$=this.service.getPayload$();
    }
}
```

I have the feeling that the event that I use from the sdk is not correctly implemented or correctly wrapped in the Observable. In the end my goal is to wrap the SDK Response into an Observable,  so that I can subscribe to its response.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a subject.
On Service Class init a subject:

```
  sdkPayloadSubject = new Subject<SdkPayload[]>();
 // transfor subject to an observable
    payloadResults$: Observable<SdkPayload[]> = this.sdkPayloadSubject.asObservable();
//add method accept each triggered sdk value
newLoadedSdkValue(newSdkPayload:SdkPayload[]){
this.sdkPayloadSubject.next(newSdkPayload);
}
```

On your getPayload function You could use above function to trigger the new value as observable instead of:

```
subscriber.next(sdkPayload);
```

use

```
this.newLoadedSdkValue(sdkPayload);
```

Then on your component class you could use the new observable format

```
    constructor (private service:TestService){
this.payloadResults$ = this.service.payloadResults$

}
```

Comment: I actually not understand  why I need to create a subject here. I am new to rxjs so maybe I am missing sth out. Can you please provide a short explanation. As well I edited my problem. And now finally getting an error in the console, I think what confuses me the most is how sdk's event is called correctly and wrapped right in the Observable, how I can then subscribe to the data stream that should be of type interface that is defined. And how to display the correct result in the template

Comment: We could use subjects to return a side effects data in other words there is some data changed after a function executed. Subject could emit and return values in the same time.